# Problem with NIntegrate over a piecewise function

Tags: numerical-integration

The following code seems to generate wrong results

```
q2 = 1/y^0.9;
G2 = 1.1 x^0.045;
b2bar = x /. Solve[G2 == 1, x][[1]]
ff = FullSimplify[PiecewiseExpand[D[Min[G2, 1], x]*x*q2]]
NIntegrate[ff, {y, 0, 1}, {x, y, b2bar}]
NIntegrate[ff, {y, 0, 1}, {x, y, 1}]
```

Since ff=0 for x>=b2bar, one would expect `NIntegrate[ff, {y, 0, 1}, {x, y, b2bar}]` and `NIntegrate[ff, {y, 0, 1}, {x, y, 1}]` to generate the same results. But `NIntegrate[ff, {y, 0, 1}, {x, y, b2bar}]` gives 0.038246 and `NIntegrate[ff, {y, 0, 1}, {x, y, 1}]` gives 0.022375.

Is there an error with NIntegrate when integrating piecewise functions? How can I avoid this?

Comment: It's not identifying the singularity in the second integral.  Adding `MinRecursion -> 1` helps. If no one else answers first, I'll try to come back to this.

Comment: Voting to close as "described in the documentation",  since `NIntegrate`'s messages hint to ways of dealing with the described problem. But I do not feel strongly about it, 65%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, `NIntegrate` does solve the condition `1.1 x^0.045 < 1` for the singularity at `x == b2bar` and this causes a problem with the integration, which is itself an issue.  But that issue can be avoided by reducing the condition to something `NIntegrate` can handle.  If we throw in the domain restriction `0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1` from the integral, or just the x component `0 <= x <= 1`, then `Reduce` will solve the condition.

```
ff = PiecewiseExpand[D[Min[G2, 1], x]*x*q2,
  Method -> {"ConditionSimplifier" -> (Quiet[
        Reduce[# && 0 <= x <= 1, x, Reals], Reduce::ratnz] &)}]
NIntegrate[ff, {y, 0, 1}, {x, y, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Insightful. I still think OP deserves my “brute force” answer.

Comment: @AntonAntonov Certainly, and `Reduce` will fail sometimes.  Both approaches are worth keeping in mind.

Comment: I would like to clarify. I meant that OP “deserves” my less insightful answer because of the way OP suspected that `NIntegrate` cannot deal with piecewise integrants. :)

Answer (score 5):

If your second numerical integration uses appropriate options nearly the same results are obtained.

(Those options can be figured out from the messages `NIntegrate` issues while evaluating your second integral.)

One such way is:

```
NIntegrate[ff, {y, 0, 1}, {x, y, 1}, 
 Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 10^6}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 1000]
```

Here is another:

```
NIntegrate[ff, {y, 0, 1}, {x, y, 1}, MinRecursion -> 3]
```

(See `res3` and `res4` in the attached screenshot.)

[image]